# Embedded.SE shutting down

Tags: discussion

Embedded.StackExchange is no longer.  [The official reason is listed here at their Area51 page:](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems)

> The Embedded Systems site didn't have enough activity during the beta and has been closed.

---

And while we're sad to see any SE site close down, Engineering benefits a bit as the community managers have [migrated the higher quality content to us](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=last30days). (*2k+ rep link*) On the other hand, the migrations have created an influx of questions that exceeds our normal rate.

Your faithful moderators would like to send out a call to the community.

**Please review the new questions**; almost all of them are still on the front page or can be found with [embedded-systems](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded-systems).

If the new questions are a poor fit for the site, please

- Edit to help them fit better if possible
- Vote to close
- Flag for moderator attention and explain what's wrong

A few questions have been self-migrated (aka copy & paste).  Please flag those so the moderators can merge the questions and keep all of the answers together.

If the questions are a good fit for the site, vote them up.  If a better answer could be provided, please do so. Also, most of these questions were migrated in without tags. They have been labeled with [embedded-systems](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded-systems) at the moment, but if there are additional tags that you feel would better describe the questions, please add those as well.

Comment: Keep in mind, these questions are *answered* and you should only edit them in ways that *preserve* the legitimacy of those answers.